# Angular Transloco usage in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, transloco

I know that the following code doesn't work, because the translation file `en.json` hasn't been loaded, when `ngOnInit()` is called:

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.translocoService.translate('hello', { value: 'world' }););
}
```

en.json

```
{
  "hello": "Hello",
}
```

---

An alternative would be subscribing to:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.translocoService.selectTranslate('hello', { value: 'world' }).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
}
```

But in my component I have 30 keys that need to be translated. Should I really subscribe to all of the 30 keys?

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngneat-transloco-8xqjqm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: What's your use case

Comment: Providing an array of column captions for a generic table component. That table component just iterates over the array and creates from those the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I found an even better solution: https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/recipes/prefetch/#prefetch-the-user-language

I now use the `APP_INITIALIZER` to preload the translation file, before the app initializes. That way the translations are always available, also in the constructor of components.

This approach is unfortunately nested in the Transloco docs to be easiliy overlooked.

Comment: I'm still struggling with translations seemingly not being available fast enough with this implementation, https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/translation-api/ doesn't seem to document the `load()` function which sounds like it could be a dispatch and not a guarantee of completion

Comment: Sounds to me like a falsy implementation, when you are using functions for the initial loading of the translations. At least I haven‘t used any functions, instead I had just imported the Transloco module

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should organize your JSON translation file to have a parent attribute containing all of your 30 translations required by your component (let's call the parent attribute `parentAttribute`, but find a better name ;)) :

```
{
  "parentAttribute": {
    "child1": "translation1"
    ...
    "child30": "translation30"
  }
}
```

Then, you should use the `translateObject` [method](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/translation-api#translateobject) provided by the transloco service :

```
const translations = this.translocoService.translateObject('parentAttribute');
```

`translations` variable should contain :

```
{
    "child1": "translation1"
    ...
    "child30": "translation30"
}
```

Comment: If my component would need 30 translations that doesn't exist already in the translations file, then yes this is a suitable solution. But half of the translations are already used in other components. So with your approach I would need to C&P the translations in the `parentAttribute`

Comment: Ok I understand your problem. You don't need to really C&P, but you can refer to an existing translation (see [this link](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/additional-functionality)). Sometimes you need to do that because you can't organize your translations so that it will be easy to pick them from different part of your app

Comment: Thank you, that was the last missing piece!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand correctly your need, but could be AfterViewInit the right lifecycle hook for you? At that point, transloco has loaded the translation files and you don't need to subscribe anymore.

Comment: Just found a good solution, please look at the other answer. Using AfterViewInit looks to me like a not so good solution, because you can't guarantee that the translation files have been loaded

Answer (score -1):

You may subscribe to the event objects, which fires when a language file is loaded. [See the documentation](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/translation-api#events)

```
ngOnInit() { // or even constructor

  this.translocoService.events$.subscribe(
    (event: TranslocoEvents) => {
      if (event.type === 'translationLoadSuccess') {

        console.log(this.translocoService`enter code here`.translate('hello', { value: 'world' }););
        // Do translation stuff

      }
    });

}
```

Comment: I also tried this and it's a bad solution, because the `translationLoadSuccess` only get's called when the translation file gets _initially_ loaded. So when you login in your application and navigate to the component, then this event has already been fired and your code will never be executed.